# How to covert .cpp to .exe in c++, using Atom and Windows 10

Tags: c++, atom-editor

So basically, i learned Python, and now I'm learning c++ and I don't know how to convert .cpp file to .exe
I'm using Windows 10 and coding in Atom. Can someone please help

Comment: You need to compile. If you have not installed a compiler you need to do so. Also, if you  are new to this and never have used your compiler from the command line I would recommend just using Visual Studio Community as learning compiler options at the same time as learning c++ is very difficult. `c++` is arguably the most difficult programming language to learn.

Comment: If you are required to use atom you could start here: [https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler)

Comment: @drescherjm C++ being the most difficult programming language is nonsense, please don't say such things. Is it harder to learn than Python for a beginner? Sure, that could be argued.

Comment: C++ is often difficult to learn is (in my opinion) due to it being taught poorly, rather than being inherently difficult.  C++ is no Malbolge.  Kate Gregory [Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) for C++ presentation (1 hour long, from CppCon 2015) nails the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't use Visual Studio I would suggest you install [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)

1. Download the software
2. Put it into C:\MinGW (just a suggestion)
3. Add the folder path to the environment variables
4. Open CMD and type g++ "filename.cpp" -o "executable name".

You can also specify multiple files by just typing successively.